# The product of non-unital rings

Tags: ring-theory

Say I have a ring $R$ which is not necessarily unital then am I correct in saying that the set $RR$ is a subset of $R$ and not necessarily equal to $R$?

Where the product of subsets $A$ and $B$ of a ring $R$ is defined to be the set of all finite sums of elements in the block product of $A$ and $B$.

I ask this because if $r \in R$ and there is no unital element then does $r$ necesscarily belong to the block product of $R$ with itself?

Comment: Yes that's right, $RR$ may be strictly smaller than $R$. Think about $2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Note, however, that it is possible for $RR$ to be equal to $R$ even in the absence of a unit. For example, the ring of all continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ of compact support does not have a unit, but $RR=R$ holds in that ring.

Comment: Is my definition of the product of sets standard? Or is my definition unique to my course?

Comment: I remember from group theory that for two subgroups $H$ and $K$ that $HK$ was the block product set. So I’m unsure why this changed for ring theory.

Comment: @Anteater23 Your definition is standard since we need finite sums for staying closed under addition. If we would only look at products of elements, the product of two ideals would not be an ideal.

Comment: In fact, your definition is the standard definition of product of ideals; $R$ is an ideal of itself, so $RR$ should be interpreted in that context.

Comment: In my notes it also says if $a\in R$ then ${\langle a \rangle }^3 \subseteq RaR$. How can we say this when the $a$ in between $R$ and $R$ is not an ideal?

Comment: @Anteater23: $RaR$ consists of all sums of elements of the form $ras$ with $r\in R$ and $s\in S$. There is no restriction to only multiplying things if they are ideals!

Comment: I’ve just asked this as a separate question where I explained myself more clearly. I’m not necessarily working with a commutative ring - sorry for not previously stating that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. Look for example at the non-unital ring $R=2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $2 \notin RR$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

Let $R$ be a ring with more than one element in which products are all zero.

Then $RR=\{0\}\neq R$.

Requiring $RR=R$ is a sort of regularity condition that can take the place of a missing identity.  For example, the "infinite direct sum" of rings $R=\oplus F_2$ does not have an identity, but $RR=R$ (since $e^2=e$ for every element.)

Comment: Why do you say that the infinite direct sum has no unity? What about (1,1,1,......)? Is it not a unit?

Comment: I mean (1,1,1...) is an identity.

Comment: @LawrenceMano The *sum* only contains things that are finitely nonzero.  So thing you’re talking about is not an element of $R$.  It’s the identity of $\prod F_2$, of course.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you.  I forgot the finite aspect of the infinite sum.